# php regex keep only alphanumerical latin characters, punctuations and html

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I already figured out how to filter out non-alphanumerical characters while keeping accents, but how can i also keep punctuations and common keyboard characters like !%$#&@*()[]:;/-+_=.,

I also need to keep all html tags and BR line breaks from the string. Is this possible ?

```
$caption = preg_replace('/[^\p{Latin}\d\s\p{P}]/u', '', $caption);
```

Comment: Maybe something like `<\/?.+?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^\p{Latin}\d\s\p{P}]` That isn't really validating that it is an HTML element though, more just that you have a `<` and a `>` with something in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It keeps all the special keyboard chars and *all* html tags
and just targets the other items.

The regex uses atomic groupings for the tags and special chars.
The result should be very quick.

Stringed and delimited form `'~..~'` :

`'~(?>(?><(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>|[!%$#&@*()\[\]^:;/+_=.,\~-])(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|[^\p{Latin}\d\s\p{P}]~'`

Raw form :

`(?>(?><(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|n‌​oscript|noembed)(?:\‌​s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S‌​\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>]‌​)?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?<‌​/\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\‌​w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+‌​\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\‌​S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?‌​)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(‌​?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?‌​)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]‌​*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*‌​?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s‌​]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]‌​*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]‌​*?))))>|[!%$#&@*()\[‌​\]^:;/+_=.,~-])(*SKI‌​P)(*FAIL))|[^\p{Lati‌​n}\d\s\p{P}]`